# Red Hat AMQ Broker 7.2.0 Jar file required for SAP integration

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic

My Client has installed this version of Red Hat AMQ Broker 7.2.0. Where do I jar file which i need to import in my SAP server. Example  it is activemq-all-5.7.0.fuse-71-7.jar

How do I find the related jar file for version Red Hat AMQ Broker 7.2.0.??

Regards,
Ragav

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `lib/client` directory in the broker distribution, and you'll find the proper client jar.